# Dart: mixin composition without extension

Tags: dart, mixins

I understand Dart mixins must not extend other classes. However, is there some way to create a composition of two mixins in some way that doesn't use an extend? For example, consider the following code

```dart
abstract class GreeterMixin{
  sayHello(String person) => print("Hello $person");
}

abstract class SmallTalkerMixin implements GreeterMixin{
  makeSmallTalk(String person){
    sayHello(person);
    print("The weather looks good");
  }
}

class Animal{
  final int nLegs;
  Animal(this.nLegs);
}

class Person extends Animal{
  final String name;
  Person(this.name): super(2);
}

class SocialPerson extends Person with GreeterMixin, SmallTalkerMixin{
  SocialPerson(String name): super(name);

  introduceSelf(String person){
    makeSmallTalk(person);
    print("My name is $name");
  }
}
```

Clearly, a smallTalker must be a greeter, but because I want to use SmallTalkerMixin as a mixin, it cannot extend GreeterMixin. Unfortunately, this means that everywhere I include SmallTalkerMixin as a mixin, I must also include GreeterMixin as a mixin.

In other words, is there a way to acheive the following using just the code above?

```dart
abstract class SmallTalkerGreeterMixin implements SmallTalkerMixin, GreeterMixin{
  sayHello(String person) => print("Hello $person");

  makeSmallTalk(String person){
    sayHello(person);
    print("The weather looks good");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is currently possible. Many limitations of mixins are supposed to be removed but there is no specific time frame until when this will happen.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a class like what you are asking for, but it won't be usable as a mixin.

```dart
class SmallTalkerGreeterMixin = SmallTalkerMixin with GreeterMixin;
```

or, equivalently,

```dart
class SmallTalkerGreeterMixin = Object with SmallTalkerMixin, GreeterMixin;
```

This creates the class you ask for, but since its superclass is either `SmallTalkerMixin` or `Object with SmallTalkerMixin`, not `Object`, you can't use it as a mixin.

With the current restrictions, there is no way to combine two mixins into one class which can again be used as a mixin - all mixins must have `Object` as supertype, and you can't add the functionality of two classes and still have `Object` as supertype.

One of the ideas of a mixin is that it refers *only* to the incremental change between a class and its superclass. All classes are defined as a superclass extended with another layer on top of it. Applying a mixin class is a way to reuse the *extension*, where normal class declarations is only a way to reuse the superclass. Since a mixin is only one layer, there is no way to combine two mixins into one.

It would definitely be a useful feature though. If you look at the `ListMixin` class, it duplicates some of the functionality of `IterableMixin`. It would be much better if it was possible to extend the `IterableMixin` and still have the result be usable as a mixin, but that's not currently possible.

Comment: I disagree (that this doesn't answer the question). It's not the answer I was hoping for, but I asked a yes/no question, and got a no response. That's fine. I would suggest it doesn't add anything further the Gunter's though - but verification from additional sources is never a bad thing :)

Comment: I've elaborated the answer some more. The answer is still "no". If/when that changes, I'll be the first to use the feature :)